# Are there any way to match a pattern in Iterable<String> in Java?

Tags: java, match, iterable

I'm trying to match a pattern for `Iterable<String> text`, the requirement is to find out the text that do not begin with `abc`, I tried to use regex `text.matches(^(?!abc).+)`, but it seems these's no `matches` method in iterable.
`

Comment: "requirement is to find out the text that *do not begin with `abc`*" in that case, instead of `.matches(^(?!abc).+)` which for positive result needs to test *entire string*, use `!word.startsWith("abc")` which will just test first 3 characters and negate result. It is also more readable: "*`if` (`it is not true` that `word starts with abc`)*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over the `Iterable` you have. E.g.:

```
for (String t : text) {
    if (t.matches("^(?!abc).+") {
        // do something with it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this and capture the matching strings.

```
List<String> strs =
        List.of("abcapple", "abcfoo", "abcbar", "abwordc");

strs = strs.stream().filter(str -> str.matches("^(?!abc).+"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(strs);
```

Prints

```
[abwordc]
```